# Ordering a column while adding an identity column in an existing table in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

Thanks to this good forum, got a number of solutions to my past queries, thanks to Google too. This is my first post in the forum although.

I have a table **order** with columns *pin, orderPath, quantity*. There are 5000 data in the table already. Now, I want to add an identy column, say *OrderID*, but with order by column *pin*.

Using the following query helps but not in the order as required.

```
ALTER TABLE order
ADD OrderID numeric(6,0) identity
```

Here's what I would like to see:

```
Pin--OrderPath--Quantity--OrderID 

11   xyz/pop    200       1 
22   kl/pod     100       2 
33   djh/dd     200       3  
44   dj/po      300       4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE orderADD 
ADD Order_ID datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of your logic requires the data to be returned or displayed in a certain order, don't rely on the database.  Explicitly put an `order by` clause in your queries to ensure consistency.

```
SELECT pin, OrderPath, Quantity, OrderID
ORDER BY pin
```

If you need data to be stored in a particular order, it's recommended to us a clustered index on the column you want orderd.  Clustered indexes keep data in order, making for faster retrieval, but keep in mind it does add cost to inserts.

```
create unique clustered index pin_idx on ORDER (pin)
```

Comment: Nor did I, that's why I went with both Indexes and Order by.

Comment: In other way, the "pin" column is also unique in its own, no duplicate rows. What I required is that when I add the identity column OrderID, it should be something like below:

Comment: Pin OrderPath Quantity OrderID

Comment: It should have a sequence OrderId and must be order by Pin

Comment: Sorry for the large number of comments, I need to check how the format works in the forums.

Comment: You should add information like this to your question, instead of putting it it comments, but I understand not all function are available until you have < 1 points.  I've change the syntax of the select to match what you are looking for, as well as editing your question to add this information in.